# How to get RqlCursor (response after running query) into java Map?

Tags: rethinkdb

I am using Rethinkdb Java driver, How can I convert RqlCursor to Map in java?

```
 RqlCursor cur = r.db("test").table("x").insert({"a":"b"})
```

How to convert this `cur` to Hashmap or Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the cursor for query results and [there is a getMap method in the result object](https://github.com/dkhenry/rethinkjava/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dkhenry/RethinkDB/RqlObject.java)

That insert query returns [certain attributes](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/insert/), you can retrieve them for example like this:

```
for(RqlObject o : cur) {
    o.getAs("inserted").toString();
    o.getAs("replaced").toString();
    o.getAs("unchanged").toString();
    o.getAs("errors").toString();
}
```